# Local Search algorithm: Why is the neighborhood structure $N : S \to 2^S$

Tags: optimization, algorithms

I am writing a paper about meta heuristics and in particular local search. My tutor pointed this out:

[image]

In every source (books, lectures, sites) I looked none explained why it is mapped like that. They all just stated that it is mapped like that. I am looking for the reasoning behind that.

Please explain why it is $2^S$.

Comment: "For each solution $s\in S$, the set $\mathcal{N}(s)$ describes the subset of solutions [...]", hence $\mathcal{N}(s)\in 2^S = $ powerset of $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Search" means looking for a point $a$ in the solution space $S$ that solves the problem (in some sense - perhaps maximizing some function on $S$).

A "local search" algorithm starts at some (nonoptimal) point $s$ and tries to find a nearby point $s'$ that's better. To do that, the algorithm needs to know which points in $S$ it should think of as near $s$. The set of those nearby points is $N(s)$, which is a subset of $S$. So you can think of $N$ as a function from $S$ to subsets of $S$, i.e. to $2^S$.

Comment: Thank you sir, I added this to my paper can now turn it in. Cheers!